# How to render the correct view when using internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

How do you render the correct template in a controller action when the template depends on the locale. For instance if you have two files `edit.html.erb` and `edit.fr.html.erb`, how do you call `render :edit` based on the locale?.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use i18n? I don't know if you have any restrictions on it...

Comment: You could do it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the private section of your controller, define the following method

```
  def locale_suffix
    locale = params[:locale]
    return '' if locale.nil? || locale == I18n.default_locale

    ".#{locale}"
  end
```

and then in your action

```
def edit
  ...
  render "edit#{locale_suffix}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def edit
  if params[:locale].present?
    render "edit.#{params[:locale]}"
  end
end
```

If the `:locale` param doesn't exist, the `edit.html.erb` template will render by default. As @Sandra's says, it would be best to just use the `I18n` strings in your template, unless you have a requirement that makes that impossible.

Comment: Interesting, but will it work in an update action where edit is rendered if there are validation errors?

Comment: No. In that case you would add an else clause that renders `:update`. As a general rule and my personal preference, I'd add this to both actions, until you need it in a third. In that case I'd move it to a private method as Obromios' answer suggests

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by I18n strings, but I do know that when I did the usual default_url_options, ```{ locale: I18n.locale }``` in the application controller, I did not need to do above. But it turned out I just need to restrict the translations to one controller and not generate any extra urls with ?locale=fr and so seem to need to do the above.

Comment: I mean that you would use the relevant `I18n` string translations in the view template itself: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization. That way you render the same template every time and call `I18n.t(:some_configuration_key)`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you asked and answered the question at first